# AutoCompleteTextView with MySQL Data

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` that I need to suggest names from a `MySQL` table.  I have only once used this before with hard coding a `string array`.

I have only seen one example, at [this](http://samplecodez.com/android/autocompletetextview.php) link, and it really wasn't much of a help.  I need to do this with an `AsyncTask`.  I know how to handle the `AsynTask` portion, but here are my questions:

I'm going to have to send each part of the phrase typed as a `param` for the `task`.  Where do I get this text `string`?

The only method I can see is a `TextWatcher` maybe.  Would that be it, or is there another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would that be it, or is there another method?

You simply need some mechanism that will "watch" changes in your inputbox and the most correct  way how to achieve it is mentioned `TextWatcher`

So implement it and in some method that provides `TextWatcher` for instance [onTextChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged), assign data from inputbox and send them as parameter to *AsyncTask* and in *onPostExecute()* method create new Adapter for your `AutoCompleteTextView` with data retrieved from `MySQL` and assign Adapter to your widget and you got it.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   if (s.length() > 1) {
      insertString = s.toString();
      new YourTask().execute(insertString);                  
   }
}
```

and in your AsyncTask, perform something like this:

```
protected List<String> doInBackground() {
   // fetchning data from MySQL
   return list;
}

public void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
   if (!result.isEmpty()) {
       SomeAdapter adp = new SomeAdapter(context, layout, result);
       actv.setAdapter(adp);
   }
}
```

**Note:** In your case is easer to make your `AsyncTask` inner class of your `Activity` class and you have direct access to `UI` components without passing them via constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what you are saying and I just need to execute it.  Ran into an early problem, I think pretty basic.  Can you see updated code at end of question?

Comment: @KickingLettuce you will set adapter in your AsyncTask method. Now pass your insertString to AsyncTask e.q. execute(insertString) and perform fetching and in onPostExecute set adapter for your autocompletetextview. Also you can have empty adapter but then i recommned you create own subclass of adapter to get more control over it.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand the portion having to do with the AsynTask.  Just my initial setup.  Can't understand why null pointer.  Am I missing something else that needs to be setup BEFORE the `AsynTask` is even called?

Comment: @KickingLettuce add your logcat, please.

Comment: I went ahead and marked you correct;  since you answered original question.  This null pointer is a side thing.  Can't figure it out at all.  But not really related.  Going to open it as separate questions since its a different topic and to keep this one clean.

Answer (score 1):

`AutoCompleteTextView` already handles this for you. 
Basically, by default, when it determinates that the list need to be filtered it calls the `performFiltering`method.

So, if you want to reuse the existing logic, just create a `AutoCompleteTextView` subclass which overrided the `performFiltering`method and put there the code for perform the filtering (in your case the AsyncTask call). Something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
        //Here the AutompleteTextView has determined that the list should be filtered
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to Add AsynTask Bellow code

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
PeopleAdapter adapter;
List<People> mList;
TextView idd;
ImageView imgspn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mList = retrievePeople();

    txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_search);

    adapter = new PeopleAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.lbl_name, mList);
    txtSearch.setThreshold(1);
    txtSearch.setAdapter(adapter);

    idd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idd);
    imgspn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgspn);
    imgspn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    txtSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Name = mList.get(position).getId();
            idd.setText(Name);
        }
    });

}

private List<People> retrievePeople() {

    List<People> list = new ArrayList<People>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/stud", "root",
                "Windouspass");
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery(
                "select name,designation_name,id from umdlv_users ut,t_designation td where ut.designation_id = td.designation_id");
        while (rs.next()) {

            list.add(new People(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return list;
}
```

}