# android autocompletetextview inside asynctask not showing

Tags: java, android-asynctask, textwatcher

I have successfully linked up my AutoCompleteTextView to data found in MySQL,in addition I am using an AsyncTask for this. What I would like to know is how can I show the dropdownlist in my TextView. I know I am getting the data Correctly because it shows in my **System.err.println()** method. Here is my code..

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_httpentity);
    AutoCompleteTextView locationupdate;

    // This is an issue I do not know how to hook
    // My autocompleteTextview here    
   AutoLocation mytask= new AutoLocation();
        mytask.execute();

    }

  private class AutoLocation extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        String line,tryy="";
    AutoCompleteTextView locationupdate;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            locationupdate=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.locationupdate);
        }




        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

            try {

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  // Other code here that I omitted because it is correct

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    tryy+=   result.append(line);
                }
   // tryy contains the MySQL data and it works successfully
   // because I can see output in System.err.println()
                System.err.println(tryy);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return tryy;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result)
        {
       // How can I pass tryy into my adapter here?

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>
 (Httpentity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,result);
                locationupdate.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        //Async Ends
        }
```

As you can see from above the **tryy** string contains the data from MySQL. I just do not know how to pass that to the adapter in **onPostExecute** . The other issue is simply on how can I now pass this to the onCreate method? For instance if this was a click method then you would use a setOnclick then have the Async execute on click but what about for AutocompleteTextview? This talks about TextWatcher but I can't seem to implement that any suggestions would be great..
[AutoCompleteTextView with MySQL Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108185/autocompletetextview-with-mysql-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(Httpentity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,result);
locationupdate.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after this put `locationupdate.showDropDown();`